# Can a standing wave indistinguishable from a travelling wave for a stationary observer?

Tags: waves

Say that you place an observer at a point in space where the non-zero amplitude of a standing soundwave is equal to the amplitude of some travelling soundwave (that is, the two opposing travelling components of the standing wave are each half the amplitude of the single travelling wave at the point within the standing wave that is being referenced). If one were able to instantaneously switch between the standing wave, and the travelling wave, the observer should hear a tone of identical frequency, and amplitude.

For example: Say you have a wave travelling to the left given by
$$
f(x, t) = A\sin(x + t)
$$
And a standing wave given by
$$
g(x,t) = A\sin x\cos t
$$

If we assume that, for the observer, they are indistinguishable at some point in space, $x$, then we know that $f(x,t) = g(x,t)$ so
$$
\begin{align}
A\sin(x + t) &= A\sin x\cos t
\end{align}
$$

After simplifying, and applying a trig identity, we arrive at the following condition:
$$
\cos x\sin t = 0
$$
We have control over $x$ since we are choosing a place to put our stationary observer, so for this to be true, then we need that
$$
\cos x = 0
$$
so if $x = \frac{\pi(2n+1)}{2}$, then the standing wave would be identical to the travelling wave for the observer.

Comment: Your question statement is missing a question mark. What even is the question? Also, no, if it is a standing wave, then your ears can be aligned such that they hear different loudness, and can thus differentiate between the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

Is your stationary observer only able to see the amplitude of the wave at a single point? If so, he will see the amplitude at that point oscillate up and down with either wave. Based on his view of that point, he will not be able to tell the waves apart.

If he watched 2 points, he would be able to tell them apart.